# Counting unique addresses from a list in column A if criteria for column B is met

Tags: worksheet-function

I am trying to get a count of unique addresses from a list of a 1000 addresses in column `A` if they are in a specific primary week list in column `B`.

In this example, Monday has 4 addresses but only 2 on them are unique.

[image: list of addresses with primary week]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Concattenate (`&` operator) B&A in C? Then countif how often that combination arrises in C. All answers with a 1 are unique. Then Sum all the ones?

Answer (score 0):

*Write Monday in Cell C2, Thursday in Cell C3 and Friday in Cell C4.*

*Enter this array formula in Cell D2, finish the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and fill it down:*

```
{=SUM(IF(C2=$B$2:$B$30, 1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$30, C2, $A$2:$A$30, $A$2:$A$30)), 0))}
```

You get Unique Count of Address for Weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with pivot table:

- select your data and go to insert - pivot table - check "Add this data to the Data Model"
  [image]
- set week as "rows"
- set address as values and apply "distinct count"
- in the screenshot below I've also added a pivot showing the unique values to be able to verify it works correctly

[image]

*"distinct count" is a relatively new feature of Excel, I think it's only from Office 2013, but I couldn't find an official source for that.*